# CMS - User confusion when creating new page and having to select template and save first to see correct fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I've made WP into a cms and there's a few niggling things that cause confusion. The main one is that when you create a page, you have to first select a template then enter a title then save as draft for it to show the correct fields on the page (I'm using the advanced custom field plugin).

Is there any way to get around this? A couple of users have now said "why aren't I seeing the correct fields to fill in?", this is down to not selecting the template and saving first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are custom fields conditional upon the Page template? Wouldn't an easier, more elegant, and more intuitive approach be to use *Custom Post Types*?

Comment: I'm using this plugin for custom fields - http://plugins.elliotcondon.com/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: A Plugin is an *implementation tool*, not a *design strategy*. What are the custom Page templates you have created? I'm guessing that they would be better suited instead as Custom Post Types - and if so, then your "niggling things" would go away, because you would no longer be dependent upon page-template conditionals for your custom fields.

Comment: I'm too far down this route (as custom fields weren't easily available at the time of building the site) to go back now.